# What is the correct way to interpret "the centre of mass of a hollow body"?

Tags: classical-mechanics, gravity

The following is claimed by my textbook:

> The centre of mass of a hollow cone with radius $r$ and height $h$ is at a height $\frac{1}{3}h$ above the base of the cone

The "hollow" part is key. It is easy to show with standard integration techniques that the C.O.M of the solid cone is at a height $\frac{1}{4}h$ above the base. To arrive at the C.O.M of the hollow body, we are supposed to take the centre of mass of an ever so slightly thickened cone and let the thickness tend to zero.

I find that it is very, very important how exactly one sets up the 'slightly thickened' aspect though: my question is, what is the correct way to set it up and why? What should "correct" even mean, here? After all, no body is truly hollow, so we have to ask ourselves what do we want from this theoretical hollow model so that it may be usable in calculations.

In the two images below, we are looking at cross sections of the cones. The quantity $\delta$ is the thickness parameter. The 'thickened' hollow cone is the space described by the gap between the blue and red triangles. Two different 'paths of approach' are shown: the first diagram is using my method. I felt it made the most sense to approximate the hollow cone, by subtracting solid cones from the interior, by using red cones that approach all sides in a fairly uniform way: no preference is given to the base or to the tip. The second diagram is what the textbook uses, where it *subtracts the base* and lets the inner cone approach the outer one non-uniformly, but by expanding to reach the tip.

It turns out this makes a huge difference to the centre of mass calculation. I'll spare you the integration, but my method produces: $\frac{1}{6}h$ as the answer. The textbook produces $\frac{1}{3}h$. More generally, if we approximate the outer cone by subtracting inner cones indented by a ratio $\gamma\delta$ away from the base, we calculate the centre of mass to be $\frac{1-\gamma}{3}$. It seems to me that all approaches are good approximations of a hollow cone, but if I had to say which is the best I'd say mine, since it isn't subtracting the base: that seems unreasonable since any real 'hollow' cone has an appreciable thickness at the base too.

[image: Diagrams]

**What is correct, and why?**

Comment: Your book is simply unclear about whether the “hollow” cone includes the base or not… is it closed or open? A classic ice cream cone is an open hollow cone.

Comment: @Ghoster I'll double check that. Suppose we do include a base in the hollow cone: do you have any thoughts about what the correct approach is?

Comment: Integrate over all surfaces with a mass per unit area.

Comment: Sounds like a geometry question rather than a physics one.

Comment: @BobD Geometry doesn’t include the concept of mass.

Comment: You checked (and I double-checked) that indeed without the base the textbook would be correct, so maybe that's the way to go. If you want to include a base area, my suggestion for some sort of reasonable approach would be uniform material thickness. But then the result depends on the opening angle of the cone... :)

Comment: Sorry, what?! This is NOT a homework question. The textbook doesn't even expect us to derive those results, I was doing it out of my own interest and stumbled on the cone example.

Comment: I thank all the above commenters for their advice

Comment: *This is NOT a homework question.* Homework-*like* questions are not necessarily actual homework. The links in the closure message should clarify what kinds of questions are considered homework-like. The actual judgement of whether it is homework-like is up to other members (or moderators), not the member posting the question.